# how to Save a file at folder at the desktop no mater what the path is?

Tags: c#, path, crystal-reports

as you can see I am exporting crystal report to a PDF file 
but my problem is that the path of the crystal report RPT file and path of saving the oupt file (PDF File) since the path to folder at desktop is will be changed between PCs  like

PC1 path code be

```
C:\Users\Xuser\Desktop
```

and on def rent pc is

```
C:\Users\XYPC\Desktop
```

so the path is not a static path .. anyway way out ?

**Update:**

now below code get the path to desktop but i am getting exception about access permissions which is access to path is denied

```
private void ExportToPDF()
    {

        ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();

        try
        {
            cryrpt.Load("INVOICE_REP.rpt");

            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
            MessageBox.Show(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));
            CrExportOptions = cryrpt.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            }
            cryrpt.Export();

            MessageBox.Show("Export Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Environment class.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` to get the path to the desktop.

David Fulop suggested using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`. What's the difference between `DesktopDirectory` and `Desktop`?

According to MSDN:

- `Desktop` is "the logical Desktop rather than the physical file system location."
- `DesktopDirectory` is "the directory used to physically store file objects on the desktop."

Source for all of the above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's great but now I got an error message about access permissions which is access to path is denied

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code which is producing that error?

Comment: I have update my code

Comment: I tired to run the exe file as administrator but same error keep showing